# A spectrum of an invertible operator does not contain $0$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, semigroup-of-operators

Let $A:D(A)\to X$ be closed linear operator in a Banach space. For some complex number $\lambda$, the resolvent operator $R(\lambda,A)$ is the inverse of the operator $\lambda I-A$ if it exists.

In [this book](http://www.math.uni-tuebingen.de/arbeitsbereiche/agfa/members/rana/engelnagel_oneparametersemigroups.pdf) about the theory of semigroup of operators, page 243, 1.13 Spectral Mapping Theorem for the Resolvent, the authors gave a formula which links the spectrum of the operator $A$ with the spectrum of its resolvent operator $R(\lambda,A)$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$.

What I don't get in this formula is why the authors need to exlude $0$ from the spectrum of the resolvent operator $R(\lambda,A)$ ? isn't $0$ already not in the spectrum of $R(\lambda,A)$ because it is an invertible operator ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resolvent set of an operator $A$ is defined as those $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $A-\lambda$ is invertible **and the inverse is a bounded operator**. The second part of this definition is important.

You are right that $R(\lambda,A) = (A-\lambda)^{-1}$ is obviously invertible, but the inverse (i.e. $(A-\lambda)$) is unbounded if $A$ is unbounded. That means that $0$ is always in the spectrum of any resolvent of an unbounded operator.

Comment: Thanks !! That makes sense now.

Comment: What is confusing is that in the definition of the resolvent set in page 239 of this book, the authors define the resolvent set as those complex numbers $\lambda$ such that $\lambda-A$ is invertible. And then, they said that the inverse is bounded as a consequence of the closed graph theorem.

Comment: Beware of the domain of A. In the definition of the resolvent set, the operator $A-\lambda$ is a bijection between D(A) and X. By the closed graph theorem the inverse is a bounded operator, that's true. But that range of that inverse is D(A), which is not the whole space X. Therefore R(A, \lambda) is never a bijection onto X.

Comment: Is $D(A)$ endowed with the graph norm $|x|_A:=|x|+|Ax|$ ? because without this norm, it is not a Banach space.

Answer (score 0):

No. D(A) is a subspace of X. It has the same norm as X

Comment: But we are not allowed to apply the closed graph theorem, because $D(A)$ endowed with the norm of $X$ is not a Banach space.

Comment: Here's how I see it, maybe this is what the authors mean: Since $A$ is a closed operator, $(D(A),|.|_A)$ is a Banach space where $|.|_A$ is the graph norm, so by the closed graph theorem/bounded inverse theorem $R(\lambda,A)$ is a bounded operator from $X$ to $(D(A),|.|_A)$ hence it is bounded from $X$ to $X$.

Comment: You don't need any graph norms. R(lambda, A) is an operator from X to X. (not subjective, the image is only D(A) or something)

Comment: Ah thanks, I just missed the fact that $A$ closed implies $R(\lambda,A)$ is also closed so it implies that $R(\lambda,A)$ is bounded by Closed Graph Theorem.